# Augment Export function to support custom number formatting

Tags: export, customization, output-formatting

It's a shame that the [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export) framework provides no support for custom formatting of real numbers. Is it possible to augment the framework so that a "NumberForm" option can be passed in that specifies what [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm) arguments should be used to format real numbers?

As an example:

```
ExportString[3.14159, "Text", "NumberForm"->{3, NumberPoint->","}]
```

should produce:

> "3,14"

Answer (score 5):

Both [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export) and [`ExportString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportString) use the common function `` System`ConvertersDump`ExportInternal `` to produce their output. In particular, any options that are fed to [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export) and [`ExportString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportString) will be present as an option to `` System`ConvertersDump`ExportInternal ``. So, we can overload this function to enable customized processing of real numbers. There are at least two mechanisms by which the built-in code processes real numbers: The formats "Table", "CSV" and others use [`CForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CForm) to format real numbers, while the format "Text" uses [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString) with [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) to format real numbers. So, the following function modifies both [`CForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CForm) and [`Real`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Real) so that custom formatting occurs:

```
System`ConvertersDump`ExportInternal[channel_, expr_, format_List, opts___] := With[
    {nf = Lookup[Flatten@{opts}, "NumberForm"]},

    With[{args=Sequence@@nf},
        Internal`InheritedBlock[{CForm, Real},
            Unprotect[{Real,CForm}];
            CForm=OutputForm@linearNumberForm[#,args]&;
            Format[r_Real,InputForm]:=OutputForm@linearNumberForm[r,args];
            System`ConvertersDump`ExportInternal[channel,expr,format,"NumberForm"->{},opts]
        ]
    ] /; !MatchQ[nf, {}]
]

linearNumberForm[e_, args__]:=With[{boxes = ToBoxes[NumberForm[e, args]]},
    Replace[boxes,
        TagBox[InterpretationBox[r_, ___],___]:>stringify[r]
    ]
]

stringify[s_String]:=If[StringMatchQ[s,"\"*\""],StringTake[s,{2,-2}],s]
stringify[RowBox[s_]]:=StringJoin[Replace[s, x_:>stringify[x],{1}]]
stringify[SuperscriptBox[_, e_]]:="10^"<>stringify[e]
```

Examples:

```
ExportString[N@Pi, "Text", "NumberForm"->{4, NumberPoint->","}]
ExportString[(N@Pi)^100, "Text", "NumberForm"->{{5,5}, NumberMultiplier->"*", ExponentFunction->(#&)}]
```

> "3,142"
>
> "5.18780*10^49"

I haven't checked this code for a variety of [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm) options, so please try it out and let me know of any deficiencies.